# acro package files in c:\Users\Bob\AppData\{Local,Roaming}\MiKTeX\2.9

Tags: miktex

I was perplexed by a message that acro.sty was missing, since I copied both of my root directories (2 localtexmf's) from one computer to another.  The acro package does *not* show up in the MiKTeX package manager.  I recall installing it as a newbie in a haze of trial and error, but I was convinced that everything would be in the two roots.

After grepping the log file, I found that there were acro package files distributed throughout the subtrees rooted at `c:\Users\Bob\AppData\{Local,Roaming}\MiKTeX\2.9`, which are not my two roots.  In MiKTeX settings, I found that these paths show up as roots when I check off the box to show MiKTeX maintained roots.  I'm not sure what MiKTeX does in maintaining its own roots.  The Roaming and Local paths are described as UserInstall and UserData, respectively.  But I thought that was the point of my two roots, which is not maintained by MiKTeX.

Since the roots in the AppData paths are maintained by MiKTeX, should I be avoiding the blythe practice of blindly copying these folder trees from one system to another?  I don't want to be messing around with parts of the file system that MiKTeX doesn't expect me to mess with.  I fear corrupting something, or having my installations clobbered.

At present, the files in the old computer are located at

```
c:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\acro\acro.sty
c:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\acro\acro0.def
c:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\acro\acro1.def
```

In the new computer, it seems safest to put them in one of my roots at

```
myRoot1\tex\latex\acro\
```

There are additional files that are not part of the package zip file.

```
c:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\mthelp\acro.html
c:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tpm\packages\acro.tpm
```

In the new computer, it seems to make sense to put the html file in

```
myRoot1\miktex\mthelp\
```

At the moment, I suspect that the tpm file is autogenerated by MiKTeX when file name database FNDB and format files are refreshed/updated via the MiKTeX settings tool.

## Afternote:

Interesting error the first time I refresh the FNDB (and only the 1st time)...

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Permission denied: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb
Data: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
Line: 686
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\cygwin\home\LongName\projects\projectName\path\to\my\1st\root
Root3: C:\Users\ShortName\Documents\LaTeX\localtexmf [this is my 2nd root]
Root4: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root5: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\ShortName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

This has been posted to the following two forums:

- [latex-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=25139)
- [stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200421/acro-package-files-in-c-users-bob-appdata-local-roaming-miktex-2-9)

Comment: Posting the `log` file would be helpful.

Comment: I already wrote some comments over at [LaTeX-Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=25139&p=85460#p85460)

Comment: @Johannes_B Questions and answers on TeX.SX! are meant to be self-contained.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Did i post this as an answer? It was supposed to be a comment informing other helpers that something has been writeen in order tohelp the OP.

Comment: @Johannes_B I meant comments too - I can't access the other site at the moment...

Comment: Thanks to Johannes_B for the advice on how to clearly post afternotes.  Note that simply adding to the original post might be one of those things that work sometimes.  For example, I've logged in from a different machine, and found that my user ID on this forum was not the same as the one with which I submitted the original post.

Comment: `acro` is part of MiKTeX. Why did you install it manually? You should install it via MiKTeX's package manager if necessary.

Comment: I installed it manually because when I first used Acro more than a year ago, we did not have the ability to connect outside of the worksite for package manager functionality and so I didn't even bother checking whether it was managed.  Recently, we *did* get the ability for the package manager to connect, but I did not know that I had to update the database in order for the package to show up.  I am figuring these things out, one late evening in the office at a time.